# What should resources be in an ACL? Models of objects or the instances of the objects?

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

Please help me implement access control lists for my PHP web application. I'm using Zend_ACL specifically.

I want fine grained, application wide control over what specific entity (be it a user or group) has access to what resource. I would like to be able to grant access to a particular resource instance, but also to all resources of that type. For example:

- User #1 has editing privileges on all posts
- User #2 is a guest editor and has edit privileges on post ID #5
- Group #1 (guest) has read privileges on everything
- The users belong to a user group who inherits from guest.

My question is this: should an ACL reference types of resources or specific instances there of? Should I grant users the fundamental, resource-type-wide priviledges using the ACL like this:

- grant edit to user #1 on post
- grant user #2 nothing more than it's inheritance
- grant group #1 read on all resources
- implement an exceptions table to track grants and denys on specific resources

Or should I create resources for all the individual instances of my different types of resources and go on a granting rampage to allow all users to read all resources? Seems rather brute-like.

My current solution is this: using resource inheritance, create a parent most resource of no type, a child of this root for each type, and then a child of each type for each instance. This allows me to grant on one particular type and deny on a few instances, or deny a particular type but grant on one instance (like for user #2 above). This unifies my permissions system nicely, however my needs are more complex. Soon, resource types will be nested. So I will different modules who can be parents or children. An example: a site wide photo gallery module, an announcements module with another more exclusive gallery residing underneath it. I'm not quite sure what to do to address this. I would still like to have the ability to grant on all galleries, or just to one, or just so some photos underneath. Bear in mind that Zend_ACL doesn't support multiple inheritance for resources.

What is the best way to implement this? All with an ACL or using some logic built into each module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just responded to [SO995925: How should I structure my tree of resources in an ACL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995925/how-should-i-structure-my-tree-of-resources-in-an-acl/1259043#1259043) and the advice I have to you is quite the same.

Its all in your head - The "Announcement Galleries" are a child resource of the "Photo Galleries".  Generic Gallery #1 parents to "Photo Galleries" while "Announcement Gallery" parents to "Announcement Galleries".  You can always add another parent resource step into your chain if you need to split the tree again.

Still a simple tree inheritance chain.

Comment: Your answer at the other question was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution plan is the way most systems work, I thought. The Windows filesystem works that way.  The very first ACL system I ever used, in DCE, worked that way.

Inheritance is what you have to figure out.  Do you inherit dynamically, or at the time the resource is created?

Comment: The inheritance is dynamic, however my resources can only have one parent. This means they can either inherit from their parent resource-type (an instance inheriting from a model resouce) or they can inherit from their parent in the structure of resources (in the example above, the gallery inherits from the announcements page). I want the functionality of both, but can't inherit from more than one thing.