# how i can make Permission system in php

Tags: php

i have table titled gorups
have
posting enum('yes','no')
delete enum('yes','no')
in the gorups table

how i can make Permission system in php
this mean

when write

```
if(Permis['posting']=='yes'){
echo ok;
}
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922553/can-i-do-it-with-only-session-or-do-i-need-acl/1922596#1922596) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370371/recommend-a-php-acl-class) and maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995925/how-should-i-structure-my-tree-of-resources-in-an-acl/1259043#1259043).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your are using MySQL, why not use [BOOLEAN or the equivalent TINYINT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) instead of ENUM? There is no reason to use strings 'yes' and 'no' when they are really booleans true and false.

Stuff like that can be handled through an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). One implementation of an ACL in PHP is [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html). If you do not want to use an ACL but just your database and your own code, you would have to write some code that queries your database for the permission of the Group, e.g. `SELECT posting from Groups where id = [groupId]`.

Comment: yes its good but i made the table enum i cant change all this

Comment: sure you can. embrace change :)